# Struts2 file download : How to optimize memory usage during file creation

Tags: struts2, download

Struts2,
I use next code to create file on server and then to write on hard drive of user computer:

struts.xml

```
<action name="download" class="com.DownloadAction">
  <result name="success" type="stream">
      <param name="contentType">application/octet-stream</param>
      <param name="inputName">fileInputStream</param>
      <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="report.xxx"</param>
      <param name="bufferSize">83886080(or more bigger)</param>
  </result>
</action>
```

action

```
public String execute() throws Exception {

    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    .... //code for writing to the buffer   

    fileInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.toByteArray());

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

The problem with java heap size arise when "buffer" very big

Simply I want next:

1. create new segment of data in "buffer"
2. write this segment to fileInputStream
3. free memory allocated for this segment in buffer
4. repeat step 1), 2) and 3)

How can I implement such algorithm?

Comment: Why are you using such a large buffer?

Comment: I use such large buffer for report which consist a big array of scientific data during month, this data retrieves from device with high frequency by time. - User can want to get such report for month